# Should we use package names as tags?

Tags: discussion, tagging

That is, if a question is about a particular LaTeX package, or the accepted answer is, should that question be tagged with the package name as tag? I think this could be a good habit.

Answer (score 18):

Yes, but IMO only if the question is also tagged with the appropriate tags for what the package does (i.e., [graphics]) so that you can find it in a search (i.e., so you wouldn't *have* to know the name of the package to find the question).

Comment: Indeed. It should be 'extra'. That way, you can easily aggregate all knowledge about a particular package, as well as do the regular stuff.

Comment: +1 yap, both should be there, package name for those who know the package name, what it does for those who doesnt know the name

Comment: We've had a similar discussion before about answer vs. question tags. See [Adding tags to a question in accordance with a provided answer](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/577/2693). I think the consensus is that tagging questions based on the answers is *not* a good idea.  So if someone asks "how do I change a section heading", and the answer involves `titlesec`, the question should *not* get a `titlesec` tag.

Answer (score 7):

yep (15 chars padding)

Comment: While I'd generally encourage you to elaborate on why you are of a certain opinion, here's a trick that could be used here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/94244/162565 `;)`